# Extjs 4.2.3 Add/Remove Container

Tags: javascript, extjs, dynamic, panel

im faceing a weird issue here,

i have a viewport - borderlayout,

my west region extends tab.panel, in the first run i have components added to the west region as tabs,

one container has a gridpanel in it, removing this container from the west region and adding it back work perfectly BUT, the grid inside it is not functional anymore, i cant select and click,listeners are not working

here is how im adding panels

```
thisControl.add({
  title: title,
  xtype: widgetName,
//items:[{xtype: widgetName}],
  closable: true,
//autoScroll: true,
  listeners: {
    'beforeclose': function(pnl, eOpts) {
        if (pnl.closeMe) {
            pnl.closeMe = false;
            return true;
        }

        Ext.Msg.show({
            title: 'Close confirmation',
            msg: 'Really close? <br />It will delete all related Information/Windows and Map Results',
            icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
            animateTarget: this,
            callback: function(btn) {

                if ('yes' === btn) {
                    pnl.closeMe = true;
                    //console.log('closing..' + widgetName);
                    _this.ClosePanelSetup(pnl.xtype)
                    _this.getPnlWestPanel().remove(pnl, true);
                    WSAVL.app.getController('WSAVL.controller.Main.WestPanel.FunctionsGridPanelWindow').DeSelectRow(pnl.xtype);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    },
    close: function(panel, eOpts) {
        console.log('Closing..');
    }
  }
});
```

and im removing the panels like that

```
_this.getPnlWestPanel().remove(pnl,true);
pnl.removeAll(false);
```

after re-adding the removed container, the gird's selection is never clear as if it is still loading the old one, and all listeners are not working and i cant select rows

thank you for any help/suggestions

Comment: how are you re-adding?

Comment: re-adding is the same way as adding, but i was thinking, is it that something has to be made to the store ? maybe i have to reset the store or something like, because other panels that has no grids, works perfectly after re-adding the container.. appreciate your help